# UnreachableBrowserException in Selenium Webdriver 2.42.2 with PhantomJSDriver 1.1.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I am doing a parallel execution of test cases using `Selenium Web Driver 2.42.2` and `Ghost Driver 1.1.0`. The below exception occurs when more tests are being added. Initially, with less number of tests, I didn't see this exception.

**Stack Trace:**

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    -----------------
    ---------------
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at memory consumption by phantomjs executable.

Seems to be the problem is in .get() method, which creates objects in PhantomJS memory time to time, without cleaning it